# Python: New line character after command

Tags: python, newline, sudo

In a program I am writing I have this:

```
SUDOPATH = subprocess.Popen(['which', 'sudo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
SUDO = SUDOPATH.stdout.read()
```

But if I attempt to do this:

```
os.makedirs(SUDO + directory)
```

It gives me an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/sudo\n'
```

How do I go about removing the new line character so I don't run in to this problem when issuing shell commands from Python?

Comment: try `os.makedirs(SUDO + directory.strip())`

Comment: Wouldn't that strip the end off of the directory and not sudo? I am still getting the same error.

Comment: ok, then do `SUDO.strip()`

Comment: a variable I stored of a full path to a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SUDO[:-1] 
#prints '/usr/bin/sudo'
```

That worked for me

EDIT:
or

```
SUDO=SUDO.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.makedirs(SUDO.strip() + directory)`